# Updating an old dataframe with conditional matching of different columns and adding new rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have an old dataframe with following columns and lot of rows and look like this

```
>old_df
date/time    Name   detect_ID   category  ID
12/1/2023    XXX    1           B        1400
12/1/2023    XXY    1,3,7       B        1402
12/1/2023    XXY    4           A        1403
12/1/2023    XXY    4           B        1407
.....
```

I have some information on **new_df** which has similar column and based on this I want to update the **old_df**. New dataframe is:

```
>new_df
date/time    Name   detect_ID   category  ID
13/1/2023    XXX    1           B        1400
14/1/2023    XXY    1,3,8       B        1402
14/1/2023    XXY    1           B        1405
.....
```

For updating I want following conditions:

1. I want to iterate through the rows of **old_df** while checking every rows of new_df and its information. But I want to check only those rows of **old_df** where *Category* column value is 'B".
2. First the program will keep in mind the first row's *ID* value of **new_df** for first iteration (and go through all rows of new_df with consecutive iteration). While iterating through rows of **old_df**. If the *ID*  of this first row of **new_df** doesnt match matches with any *ID*  of **old_df** it will take that full row from **new_df** and add it as a new row of **old_df** while creating a new column in **old_df** named *Identify* and assigning a value *new*.

If the *ID*  of this **new_df** matches with any *ID*  of **old_df**, it will go through that specific row's *detect_ID*  column value. Now few things can happen :

A. If that specific *detect_ID*  value of **old_df** matches with that first row's *detect_ID*  value of **new_df**, it will take that specific row of **new_df** and replace the matched row of **old_df**, while the newly created column *identify* will have value *updated*. In this case. Also, as you can see here *detect_ID*  has multiple values : 1,2,3 I want to check for each of them separately and some of these digits maybe integer. so basically split them with **,** and converting them to integer.

B. If that *detect_ID* value of **old_df** doesnt match with that first row's *detect_ID*  value of **new_df**, it will take that full row from **new_df** and add it as a new row of **old_df** while going in column *identify* and assigning a value *new*.

3. For the rows of **old_df**, that "ID" value did not match with any rows of **new_df** having same 'ID or same 'ID' but no match on ' detect_ID' value, will remain unchanged in old_df and have value *unchanged* in *identify* column.

I want this to iterate through all rows of **old_df** until every row of **new_df** is updated in **old_df** .

For the givene example, I want output dataframe like following:

```
>output
date/time    Name   detect_ID   category  ID   identify
13/1/2023    XXX    1           B        1400   updated  [Case A] 
14/1/2023    XXY    1           B        1402   updated  [Case A with multiple detect_ID]
14/1/2023    XXY    3           B        1402   updated
12/1/2023    XXY    7           B        1402   unchanged  [Step 3, Id matches but detect_id do not ]
14/1/2023    XXY    8           B        1402   new        [Case B]
12/1/2023    XXY    4           A        1403   unchanged   
12/1/2023    XXY    4           B        1407   unchanged [Step3 , id not found in new_df]
```

I am using following code but it seems not working as the way I want. It gives a lot of duplicate and doesn't iterate through a lot of rows of **old_df** too.

```
old_df = pd.read_csv('old.csv')
new_df = pd.read_csv('new.csv')

# Create a set of tuples representing the unique (ID, Detector Id) pairs in the old dataframe
unique_pairs = set()
for _, row in old_df.iterrows():
    detector_ids = [int(x) for x in str(row['Detect_ID']).split(',')]
    for detector_id in detector_ids:
        unique_pairs.add((row['ID'], detect_id))

# Iterate over the rows in the new dataframe and check if their (ID, Detector Id) pair is in the set of unique pairs
new_rows = []
updated_rows = []
for _, row in new_df.iterrows():
    detector_ids = [int(x) for x in str(row['Detect_ID']).split(',')]
    for detector_id in detector_ids:
        if (row['ID'], detector_id) in unique_pairs:
            old_row = old_df.loc[(old_df['ID'] == row['ID']) & (old_df['Detect_ID'].str.contains(str(detector_id)))]
            if not old_row.empty:
                old_row = old_row.iloc[0]
                old_row['Date/Time'] = row['date/time']
                old_df.loc[(old_df['ID'] == row['ID']) & (old_df['Detector_ID'].str.contains(str(detector_id))), 'date/time'] = old_row['date/time']
                updated_rows.append(old_row)
        else:
            row['Identify'] = 'new'
            new_rows.append(row)
            unique_pairs.add((row['ID'], detector_id))

# Append the new rows to the old dataframe and write the updated dataframe to a new file
old_df = old_df.append(new_rows, ignore_index=True)
for row in updated_rows:
    row['Identify'] = 'updated'
old_df = old_df.append(updated_rows, ignore_index=True)
old_df.to_csv('updated.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What happened to the last row of the `new_df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on [`df.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) nearly always implies a suboptimal approach to manipulations in `pandas` (see e.g. this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24870953/18470692)). Here's an approach using [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for the important part.

**Step 1**

Make sure that all the values in column `detect_ID` are strings by applying [`Series.astype(str)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html). Now, use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and  [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to get entries like `1,3,7` into separate rows. Apply to both `dfs`. At this stage, we can change the type (back) to `int` for all values in `detect_ID` (assuming that your data indeed consists of numeric characters).

Since we only want to check on rows that have value `B` in column `category`, filter out any non-`B` values from `new_df` with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (though, in your current example no such value exists).

```
old_df['detect_ID'] = old_df['detect_ID'].astype(str).str.split(',')
old_df = old_df.explode('detect_ID', ignore_index=False)
old_df['detect_ID'] = old_df['detect_ID'].astype(int)

new_df['detect_ID'] = new_df['detect_ID'].astype(str).str.split(',')
new_df = new_df.explode('detect_ID', ignore_index=False)
new_df['detect_ID'] = new_df['detect_ID'].astype(int)
new_df = new_df[new_df['category'].eq('B')]

# `dfs` now as follows
old_df

   date/time Name detect_ID category    ID
0  12/1/2023  XXX         1        B  1400
1  12/1/2023  XXY         1        B  1402
1  12/1/2023  XXY         3        B  1402
1  12/1/2023  XXY         7        B  1402
2  12/1/2023  XXY         4        A  1403
3  12/1/2023  XXY         4        B  1407
```

**Step 2**

Apply `df.merge`. We want to merge on `['Name','detect_ID','category', 'ID']`, keep all the entries from both sides (so: `how='outer'`), and also add an `indicator` column (calling it `identify`), which will tell us the source of each row. Adding custom suffixes (e.g. `'_old'` instead of default `'_x'`) for clarity's sake.

```
res = old_df.merge(new_df, on=['Name','detect_ID','category', 'ID'], 
                   how='outer', indicator='identify', suffixes=('_old','_new'))

res

  date/time_old Name detect_ID category    ID date/time_new    identify
0     12/1/2023  XXX         1        B  1400     13/1/2023        both
1     12/1/2023  XXY         1        B  1402     14/1/2023        both
2     12/1/2023  XXY         3        B  1402     14/1/2023        both
3     12/1/2023  XXY         7        B  1402           NaN   left_only
4     12/1/2023  XXY         4        A  1403           NaN   left_only
5     12/1/2023  XXY         4        B  1407           NaN   left_only
6           NaN  XXY         8        B  1402     14/1/2023  right_only
7           NaN  XXY         1        B  1405     14/1/2023  right_only
```

**Step 3**

At this stage, we want to decide on which value we need to keep for column `date/time`. We need the values from `_new` for all rows (1) that exist in both `dfs`, and (2) that exist only in `df_new`. Since `left_only` entries will have `NaN` values in column `date/time_new`, we can rely on [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to accomplish this:

```
res['date/time'] = res['date/time_new'].where(res['date/time_new'].notna(),
                                              res['date/time_old'])
```

**Step 4**

The following remains to be done:

- Updating the values for column `identify`. We can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for this.
- Selecting the correct columns from `res` in the correct order. Let's use the column names from `df_old` plus `identify` inside [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), and also chain [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for this. Let's also here use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
mapper = {'both': 'updated',
          'left_only': 'unchanged',
          'right_only': 'new'}

res['identify'] = res['identify'].map(mapper)
res = (res.loc[:, list(old_df.columns) + ['identify']]
       .sort_values(['ID', 'detect_ID'])
       .reset_index(drop=True))

res

   date/time Name  detect_ID category    ID   identify
0  13/1/2023  XXX          1        B  1400    updated
1  14/1/2023  XXY          1        B  1402    updated
2  14/1/2023  XXY          3        B  1402    updated
3  12/1/2023  XXY          7        B  1402  unchanged
4  14/1/2023  XXY          8        B  1402        new
5  12/1/2023  XXY          4        A  1403  unchanged
6  14/1/2023  XXY          1        B  1405        new
7  12/1/2023  XXY          4        B  1407  unchanged
```

---

N.B. As mentioned by @Ashyam in the comments above, your desired result doesn't  have the row for ID `1405`, which exists only in `df_new`. I'm here assuming that you *do* want this entry in the new `df`. If not, you can get rid of it as follows:

```
res = res[res['ID'].isin(old_df['ID'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Of course, this operation could then in fact already be applied to `new_df`. Cf. the filter for value `B` in column `category` above.

Comment: Hi! when I use df.explode(), it also explodes the single value and convert them to Nan. How should I stop this?

Comment: After running  '  old_df['detect_ID'] = old_df['detect_ID'].str.split(',')  ' , all single integer values turns into Nan and values like 1,3,7 turns into [1,3,7]. I know also that .explode will turn the single integers to Nan as well.  How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm. Could you see if `old_df['detect_ID'] = old_df['detect_ID'].astype(str).str.split(',')` and equivalent for `new_df` work? So, with `.astype(str)` added. I think that the issue is that the single values are type `int`; I assumed that all were `str`. If you do `str.split` on a column with both `str` and `int` (or `float`) vals, the latter ones will become `NaN`.

Comment: You're welcome! Updated the answer with the `astype(str)` part.